# Is it safe to delete Temp folder which is inside Android SDK path?

Tags: android

I just found that all the updates downloaded from SDK Manager are stored in **Temp** folder inside the Android SDK folder.

I just wanted to know whether it is safe to delete all the contents inside the temp folder?

Comment: Yes - it will just download any missing components again. But if you want to make sure, just move the folder first and re-run the SDK manager.

Comment: @adelphus I'll try it out. Thank you.

Comment: just move it to another directory and test :)

Answer (score 14):

Android Studio 4.1

1. Open SDK Manager.
2. Click the "Optimize disk space" button at the top right corner.
3. The temp folder, along with other cache folders, is included in the delete list.

Comment: Very helpful! Freed up 50GB by clicking one button!

Answer (score 8):

i deleted temp Folder in android sdk folder and after that i have not any problem, so yo can delete it safely :)