# My Android SDK takes up too much space, and .temp directory takes up 90+ GB of space. What does the .temp directory do?

Tags: android, android-studio

I was alarmed when I checked the amount of storage my "System" files took up on my Mac:

[image: System Storage Allocation]

So I went into /Users/[User]/Library/Android and saw that my SDK took up 150+ GB of space! So I got the info of all the files inside of the SDK but saw that they clearly do not add up to 152.64 GB. Then I used Cmd+Shift+Dot(.) to show all of my hidden files and saw that this .temp directory took up 91.89 GB of space. So my question is, what is it for?
[image: All the directories shown without Cmd+Shift+Dot(.)]
[image: .temp file]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the answer: Turns out the .temp folder just stores past SDK Manager download/update operations: [Check this Stack Overflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32290118/is-it-safe-to-delete-temp-folder-which-is-inside-android-sdk-path)

So I just deleted it and freed 90 GB of space.

[image]

(Turns out I had a huge amount of failed installations.)

Comment: Also check out the system-images directory. It contains the images for the emulator. I have only two images (API 21 and API 29) and it's only 5GB. Maybe there are some which you are no longer using. The image directories can be deleted manually (at least on Windows), the AVD Manager then shows a warning icon of your accidentally deleted one which you still want to use, and you can then easily install it again.

Comment: @DanielF Thank you! I will try it. (70 GB for System files is still quite a lot.)

Answer (score 1):

You should probably check out the system-images directory and uninstall what you don't need.